# Hide/Silence ChromeDriver window

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I launch Selenium's WebDriver (Chromedriver). A console window (chromedriver.exe) runs and it opens Chrome. I need to know how I can hide those like a silent mode because I get messy when there are too many open. I am using C#.

Comment: See answer here https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7898/selenium-c-4-0-release-says-you-can-hide-the-command-prompt-how-do-you-actual

Answer (score 46):

As of Chrome 59, you can now also hide the chrome browser window by using headless mode:

```
options.AddArgument("headless");
```

and in combination with:

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
```

it runs in complete silence.

Comment: as of chrome 79, there is no such method as "HideCommandPromptWindow" in ChromeDriverService object.

Answer (score 26):

To my knowledge it's not possible to hide the browser.
However, you can hide the console and set the browser offscreen:

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--window-position=-32000,-32000");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.uk");
```

Comment: That does not work because HideCommandPromptWindow does not exist

Comment: The HideCommandPromptWindow property is part of the official Selenium C# client library 2.52.0.0:
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.52/selenium-dotnet-2.52.0.zip

Answer (score 0):

Hello chrome driver command hide coding

```
public IWebDriver drv;
public AnaSayfa()
{
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    drv = new ChromeDriver(service);
    InitializeComponent();
}
void BekraHayrNesterGo()
{
    drv.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.example.com/");
}
```

This shape can hide cmd

Comment: Please do not enter links to your own website, especially without attribution that it is indeed your website. Since it seems irrelevant to the answer, I have changed to the default `example.com`. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), and refrain from linking to non-English websites in the future, as Stack Overflow is strictly English-only.

Answer (score 0):

Another hack is to make proxy executable and open hidden process.

rename **chromedriver.exe** as **driver.exe**

Build executable as **chromedriver.exe** from below code. Must use `Application Type` as `Windows Forms Application`

```vb
'chromedriver.exe
Module Main
    Sub Main(Args As String())
        Dim Info As New ProcessStartInfo("driver.exe", String.Join(" ", Args))
        Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        Process.Start(Info).WaitForExit()
    End Sub
End Module
```

And use like

```vb
Dim Options As New ChromeOptions()
Options.BinaryLocation = "C:\Program Files\Slimjet\slimjet.exe"
Dim Driver = New ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory, Options)
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.example.com") '
```

Note: It assumes both executables are in same directory.