# Prevent user from closing Selenium-driven Firefox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

While running a Selenium-driven session of Firefox, can I prevent user from closing browser's window, or, at least, subjecting it to a confirmation so that they can avoid doing so by accident?

I'm using Selenim with Winforms VB.NET application, on Windows.

Comment: Did you try running it in headless mode? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818436/hide-silence-chromedriver-window

Comment: User must perform login using a digital certificate token before the automated part kicks in, so I don't think headless would be an option for me... But thanks anyway.